# When should the tag 'russia' be used as against 'roscosmos'?

Tags: discussion

The space program under the erstwhile [USSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Union) was highly decentralized. The Russian Federal Space Agency aka [Roscosmos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roscosmos) was constituted by presidential decree after the Russian Federation emerged from the USSR.

The thing is, here on SpaceEx.SE, the tag ['russia'](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia) was used originally. The tag ['roscosmos'](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roscosmos) is a new entity. I started to apply the latter tag; then realized the tag-alternation may affect search-engine visibility.

- Should questions relating to **pre-1992/Roscosmos** space missions be tagged 'russia', and **post-1992/Roscosmos** space missions be tagged 'roscosmos'?
- Should all questions pertaining to space missions with a Russian/USSR affiliation **carry both 'roscosmos', and 'russia' tags**, or [v.v](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice_versa#vice_versa)?
- In the event of the latter i.e. tag with both 'russia', and 'roscosmos', which takes precedence when the **5-tag limit** is met?
- Should 'roscosmos' be **deleted as redundant**?

Comment: It is not that Russians suddenly decided to join all of their space industry under Roscosmos only in 1992.  The coordinating functions currently held by Roscosmos were provided by the *Ministry of General Machine Building* in the USSR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roscosmos is not the only component of the Russian space program. As such, it is definitely not redundant. I suggest tagging the post with both "Russia" and "Roscosmos" if you want to optimize visibility.

---

To solve the pre-1991 space dilemma, I suggest using the [soviets](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soviets) tag suggested by Tildal below rather than [russia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia).

Comment: What if the 5-tag limit is already full?

Comment: @Everyone You optimize according to which tags are most important to the post.

Comment: Soviet era should really be tagged something else than with "Russia" though, since it was a confederation of now independent states, Russia being but a member (albeit the biggest one). So if "soviet-space-program" is too long then alternatives I can think of could be "ussr", "red-space" (it's often quoted with this name so I don't think it's offensive, correct me if I'm wrong), or simply "soviets" (IMO plural, because there were many confederate states in it).

Answer (score 3):

*Russia* for anything related to the Soviet Union and Russian Federation in general. RF is the cessionary of the USSR in many aspects, including the space program.

*USSR* to stress the difference between then and now. Please don't use *Soviets* tag. You wouldn't expect *Yankees* to denote US space program, would you?

*Roscosmos* only in the context where it is opposed to other parts of the Russian space industry.

> Should questions relating to pre-1992/Roscosmos space missions be tagged 'russia', and post-1992/Roscosmos space missions be tagged 'roscosmos'?

*Russia* is okay for both, I suppose.
Many projects are contionous lineages, so typically one can't tell. In general, one needs an access to classified documentation to tell if a project started already in Roscosmos times or has been ended pre-1992.

> Should all questions pertaining to space missions with a Russian/USSR affiliation carry both 'roscosmos', and 'russia' tags, or v.v?

Mark it *Russia*, I'd say.
All *Roscosmos* projects can be marked with *Russia*.

> In the event of the latter i.e. tag with both 'russia', and 'roscosmos', which takes precedence when the 5-tag limit is met?

If there is a need for *Roscosmos* arises it has precedence.

For example a question discussing relations of RKK Energia, Sea Launch and Roscosmos could get the *Roscosmos* tag.

> Should 'roscosmos' be deleted as redundant?

I'd say keep it, but use it to fine tune questions.